# How to create php pagination without page numbers

Tags: php, zend-framework, pagination, zend-framework2, zend-paginator

I need to create pagination and it should not have page numbers as if I have it then I need to load all data at page loading.(I was ordered to do so)

I am little bit lost. Don't know where to start Even a little help is highly appreciated.

- using zend framework 2(MVC)
- new to php and zend
- Prefer not to use library

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by "it should not have page numbers as if I have it then I need to load all data at page loading"

Comment: pagination with out pages is an oxymoron.

Comment: I'm going to call a service which is return the relevant data set. I just have to worry about the offset and the number of items displayed

Comment: The question is unclear. Please look into making it clearer. Pagination, but not pagination?

Comment: So, What you mean is that you cannot have page numbers listed under the results, but just a forward and a back button. You keep track of what offset/limit results are being currently viewed by user, and depending on if the user clicks back/forward, you will send an appropriate request to server with offset and limit as parameters. The server based on php/Zend should return results based on this offset and limit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming, What you mean is that you cannot have page numbers listed with the results on your page, but just a forward and a back button. You keep track of what offset/limit results are being currently viewed by user, and depending on if the user clicks back/forward, you will send an appropriate request to server with offset and limit as parameters. The server based on php/Zend should return results based on this offset and limit.

I have had a precursory look at [Zend Pagination](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.paginator.usage.html) and it seems to me that it should work for you.